# Two groups to generate html tag

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help with regex.

https://regex101.com/r/r3pTh0/2

I kinda have it working with the following regex but still need help:

```
\<\%= image_tag image_url\(\“(.+?)\”\)|\“(.+?)\” %>
```

replaceing it with:

```
<img src="\1" alt="\2">
```

python code:

```
originalData = re.sub('<%= image_tag image_url("(.+?)")+, :alt => "(.+?)\" %>', r'<img src="\1" alt="\2">', originalData, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

But it does not seem to be replacing anything.

Have a string:

```
<%= image_tag image_url(“/blog/assets/images/2018-11-15/dribbble-developer-interview-jeffrey-chupp.png”), :alt => “Developer interview with Jeffrey Chupp, Director of Engineering at Dribbble” %>
```

replace it with html img tag:

```
<img src="/blog/assets/images/2018-11-15/dribbble-developer-interview-jeffrey-chupp.png" alt="Developer interview with Jeffrey Chupp, Director of Engineering at Dribbble">
```

2. would it also be hard to add http://somesite.com at the beginning for image link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are encountering this error because you selected the PHP flavor of regex on regex101.com.

Simply switch over to the Python flavor and the website fixes the regex for you. The command should be:

```
originalData = re.sub(r"\<\%= image_tag image_url\(\“(.+?)\”\)+\, :alt => “(.+?)\” %>", r'<img src="\1" alt="\2">', originalData, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

As for adding a domain prefix to the image src, simply replace `src="` with `src="https://somesite.com` in a second regex pass.

Or you could add the domain right before your replacement string like this `'<img src="https://somesite.com\1" alt="https://somesite.com\2">'`